# How to deal with comments containing wrong information

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

Sometimes people leave comments with blatantly wrong information.  Since this is a learning site, I was wondering if these should be responded to and left intact or flagged in some way to have them removed in hopes that the poison of misinformation doesn't spread.  I'm inclined to think they should just be removed but none of the existing flags seems appropriate.

Comment: mods don't typically deal with removing things due to being innacurate, but, with comments, we the community have no tools to do it ourselves either. I usually just point out tha the comment is wrong with another comment.

Comment: ok, so flagging comments because of inaccuracy would be inappropriate?  it bothers me because there is no way to downvote, and sometimes a response may be buried deep below the original comment, making it a coin toss that someone reading will even see your correction.

Comment: This is exactly why answers should be posted as answers. So that blatantly wrong information can be downvoted.

Comment: You *could* flag as not constructive, since they are ultimately not constructive, by definition. But like Pie guy said below, moderators don't evaluate flags or posts based on technical accuracy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I'm inclined to think they should just be removed but none of the existing flags seems appropriate.

No. There is no appropriate flag, because moderators won't evaluate technical correctness (either for answers *or* comments).

---

The appropriate action is to leave a "counter" comment of your own. Or, if you are able to answer the question, write a correct answer that proves the comment wrong.

Upon reading your response, most commenters will either delete their comment themselves, or they will try to "counter" comment again to explain why they think they're right.

Comment: Note that you should only post an answer to answer the question.  Don't just answer to respond to a comment.  Of course, if a comment says, "you can't do X" then posting an answer that shows how to do X would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Servy _"you can't do X" then posting an answer that shows how to do X would be perfectly fine._ That's merely what I meant there.

Comment: I know that that's what you meant, I just want to make sure people don't misunderstand what you were saying and think that they can post an answer to respond to a comment without actually answering the question in the process.

Comment: *"counter" comment* - this. It will get upvoted and that's further readers will notice/read. Incorrect comments are actually very good addition to show common mistakes or misunderstanding, there counter-comment will explain things better. High rep guys often drag those into their answers (I'd even say what sometimes wrong comment is a motivation for answer to happens). Leave wrong comments please, moderators will deal with excessive number anyway, reading a few shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Sinatr unless it's old and the fastest gun in the west is already gone.

Comment: Not that many commenters will delete their comment, especially for old users who don't visit StackOverflow anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Proposition of feature for StackOverflow: "*undisplayed downvotes for comments*".

The principe would be to allow downvoting comments, but downvotes wouldn't be subtracted to the displayed score. Only high ranked users, like Trusted users or Moderators would know the number of downvotes.

Comments with twice more downvotes than upvotes (and minimum 5 downvotes) would go on a *very low quality comment queue*.

Examples:

- 0 upvotes with 5 downvotes would display a total of 0 and be added to the queue
- 3 upvotes with 2 downvotes would display a total of +3
- 3 upvotes with 6 downvotes would display a total of +3
- 3 upvotes with 8 downvotes would display a total of +3 and be added to the queue
- 100 upvotes with 150 downvotes would display a total of +100

Comment: I like it, a genuine attempt at a community driven answer for a community driven site.+1